# ServiceStack Razor _Layout not rendered

Tags: c#, razor, servicestack-razor

Hello all ServiceStack users.  If you are like me, you really enjoy working with that beautiful framework.  Then you want to try Razor...and you wonder why is this so complicated to configure the darn thing.

I finally got everything in place (I think) but for some reason, the view is rendered but not the _Layout.  I have only one _Layout file and a view both inside the Views folder.  The @RenderBody() is getting me a message that it does not exist in the current context.  Could it be the reason?
What am I missing?

Comment: Note: any shared Layouts or partial views should ideally be stored in `/Views/Shared`

Answer (score 1):

Just before posting, I saw a similar question "ServiceStack Razor Engine not rendering Layout (_Layout.cshtml)" which made me think...I had forgotten to change the Copy to output directory to "Copy if newer".

Hope it will help someone else.  Not quite good with Web stuff yet...